# Disparar evento a un componente Livewire (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire

Estoy haciendo es un contador de productos en un carrito de compras. Al agregar un producto debo incrementar el contador y decrementar cuando quito. Para eso he creado un componente ***livewire CartCounter*** con: *`php artisan make:livewire CartCounter`*
En *`app/Http/Livewire`* tengo *`CartCounter.php`* con éste código:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class CartCounter extends Component
{
  public $count = 0;

  protected $listeners = ['addProd' => 'increment',
                          'removeProd' => 'decrement'];

  public function increment()
  {
      $this->count++;
  }

  public function decrement()
  {
      $this->count--;
  }

  public function render()
  {
      return view('livewire.cart-counter');
  }
}
```

Y en la vista del componente:

```
<div>
  <div id="carrito" class="d-flex">
    <div style="vertical-align: top">Carrito</div>
    <i class="material-icons" id="iconCarrito">shopping_cart</i>{{ $count }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Ahora bien, tengo 2 botones (fuera del componente CartCounter) para agregar y restar un productos, para sumar este:

```
<button wire:click="$emitTo('cart-counter','addProd')">+</button>
```

Y para restar este:

```
<button wire:click="$emitTo('cart-counter','removeProd')">-</button>
```

Se visualiza y se inicializa correctamente en cero pero luego al hacer clic en los botones no modifican el valor del contador y no me muestra ningún error, no sé qué me puede estar faltando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resuelto, el problema era que no estaba enviando el $emitTo() desde un componente livewire sino de un button común, lo dejo respondido por si alguien tropieza con lo mismo.